# How to correctly transfer RSS feeds between Outlook profiles

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rss

I had to move my RSS feeds (and everything else, for that matter) to a new Outlook 2007 profile. I was able to export and import them via PST file.

However, the new profile fails to update the RSS feeds. What can I do? I have not been able to find any menu items to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

When exporting Personal Folders, the RSS settings are not included. The correct way to export/import RSS feeds in Outlook 2007 is by exporting as an OPML file. When imported, Outlook will re-download RSS feeds, and update them.

The only drawback with this method is that you will lose older posts. These may be exported/imported via PST file, though.